# Two search Edit Texts into a single activity, but only one works

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Showing an image with searching car name and it works, both same queries but location does not work]

As you see here i am trying to make 2 search bars into a single activity, one for searching car name and the other is for searching by location.
Both queries are the same and should be the same, but only searching by car name works but not location for some reason, When I do search with location it just brings empty posts as "0 Results".

I am trying to make both search consistent with each other, means if i search car name with lexus the results should give me all lexus related and if i search location perhaps in Dubai, I want All Lexus in Dubai only.

I am not really sure if i do understand how both work with each other.

```
package com.capstone.araba.Fragments;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.capstone.araba.Adapter.PostAdapter;
import com.capstone.araba.Model.Post;
import com.capstone.araba.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
{

    private PostAdapter postAdapter;
    private List<Post> postList;



    private List<String> followingList;

    private ProgressBar progress_circular;
    private EditText search_bar, search_bar2;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home_fragment, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        search_bar = view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        search_bar2 = view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar2);
        postList = new ArrayList<>();
        postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), postList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);


        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        progress_circular = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular);

        checkFollowing();
        readPostsSearch();
//        readPostsSearch2();

        search_bar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                searchPosts(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        search_bar2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence2, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                searchPosts2(charSequence2.toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    private void searchPosts(String s){
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("carType")
                .startAt(s)
                .endAt(s+"\uf8ff");



        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    postList.add(post);
                }

                postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void searchPosts2(String l)
    {
        Query querys = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("location")
                .startAt(l)
                .endAt(l+"\uf8ff");

        querys.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    postList.add(post);
                }

                postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    private void readPostsSearch() {

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (search_bar.getText().toString().equals("") || search_bar2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    postList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);

                        postList.add(post);

                    }

                    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

```
package com.capstone.araba.Model;

public class Post {
    private String postid;
    private String postimage;
    private String publisher;
    private String carType;
    private String price;
    private String model;
    private String distance;
    private String color;
    private String location;


    public Post(String postid, String postimage, String publisher, String carType, String price, String model, String distance, String color, String location) {
        this.postid = postid;
        this.postimage = postimage;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.carType = carType;
        this.price = price;
        this.model = model;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.color = color;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Post() {
    }

    public String getPostid() {
        return postid;
    }

    public void setPostid(String postid) {
        this.postid = postid;
    }

    public String getPostimage() {
        return postimage;
    }

    public void setPostimage(String postimage) {
        this.postimage = postimage;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getCarType() {
        return carType;
    }

    public void setCarType(String carType) {
        this.carType = carType;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, reveal your ```Post``` class to us.

Comment: do you mean the Post.class model? sure i will edit now

Comment: It looks like that your main problem is about making complex query to your Firebase database. I've spent a little time studying possibilities of this service and found that it's impossible to make complex query (in your case there are two inputs: carType and location). Firstly I thought we could combine more than one ```.orderByChild("type").startAt(s).endAt(s+"\uf8ff")``` calls, but found it's not supported. Actually I've found some tricks for imitating "complex query", but it's 200% kludge. Try googling "complex query firebase", but get ready to be dissapointed.

Comment: I will read about complex queries too, thanks boss!